# Keys that spring into existence if checked with exists

Tags: perl, associative-array

If a perl-hash is declared like so:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %h;
```

I can then check for the existence of keys within this hash with `exists`:

```
if (exists $h{k3}) {
  print "k3 exists\n";
}
else {
  print "k3 doesn't exist\n";
}
```

Since `k3` does not exist, the script prints `k3 doesn't exist`.

I can also check for the existence `ka` in `k3`:

```
if (exists $h{k3}{ka}) {
  print "k3 ka exists\n";
}
else {
  print "k3 ka doesn't exist\n";
}
```

Unfortunately, this creates the key `k3`, so that another

```
if (exists $h{k3}) {
  print "k3 exists\n";
}
else {
  print "k3 doesn't exist\n";
}
```

now prints `k3 exists`.

This is a bit unfortunate for my purposes. I'd rather not want perl to create the `k3` key.

I can, of course, check for `ka` within `k3` with something like

```
if (exists $h{k3} and exists $h{k3}{ka})
```

which doesn't create the key `k3`. But I wonder if there is a shorter (and imho cleaner) way to check for `ka` within `k3`.

**Edit** The question was *marked as duplicate*. Unfortunately, the only answer in the referred question that mentions `no autovivification` has only one upvote there, and is not marked as accepted answer. For my purposes, the `no autovification` is the feature I needed to know (and that I was unknowingly after). So, I leave my question here as I think the accepted answer in the other question is not the optimal one.

Unfortunatly, nobody so far answered with `no autovification` which I would like to accept. I might therefore answer my own question.

Comment: “Autovivification” usually does what you want it to: let intermediate references spring into existence. For testing nested structures with `exists`, this is unfortunate. `and`ing the various levels together is the usual approach, but [`no autovivification`](https://metacpan.org/module/autovivification) may help (I've never used that module).

Comment: [`no autovivification`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?vivification)

Comment: @amon: You should promote that to an answer

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is to nest your ifs:

```
if (exists $h{k3}) {
  print "k3 exists\n";
  if (exists $h{k3}{ka}) {
    print "k3 ka exists\n";
  }
  else {
    print "k3 ka doesn't exist\n";
  }
}
else {
  print "k3 doesn't exist\n";
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of the word "simplest" :-) I would say the simplest thing is to use "no autovivification".

Comment: Simplest in that it only moves around the code he has without adding any more.  Also simplest in that it doesn't perform redundant tests.